# How to access Magento SOAP WSDL

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to understand the way SOAP from Magento works, so I can use it from an external application.(Magento v1.9.2)
So in order to use the web service from my third party application, I need a WSDL to interpret. How can I access the **default** Magento SOAP **WSDL files**?

Where are they?

For instance, I try to acces the SOAP methods from Delphi XE, and for that I need to import a WSDL file.

I searched the web for the SOAP API specifications and I found this:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html

as an example on how to access the SOAP from php...

But as I said from Delphi I need to import a WSDL in order to be able to work with the web service.

So how can I get a hold of the WSDL files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- SOAP V1: http://magentohost/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl (this one is more like RPC, no concrete operations defined in WSDL, just `call`)
- SOAP V2: http://magentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 . For strongly-typed languages use this one and remember to enable WS-I compliance mode on Magento side: `Services > Magento Core API > WS-I Compliance to Yes`

Comment: Thanks, I already suceeded, but +1 for both versions of SOAP. However, for others that encounter my problem, make sure that, if you don't have friendly URL's enabled in magento, add index.php to the path, before /api